# EEG important values visualization

Tags: eeg, visualization

i have an array contains the EEG signal values called inputSignal, and another array contains the importance degree or the attribution value of the corresponding element in inputSignal array ,
i want to visualize the eeg signal as a graph and the corresponding importance values as a background for it exactly the same as the first figure :
[image]

or coloring the signals based on their importance values as the second figure:

[image]

Comment: Hi Soumia, and welcome. We need more from you to be able to help you. Critically, what plotting tool are you using?

Comment: @Jdip Thank you, I am actually using python BUT i can use matlab or other tools to get similar results.